# How to update a Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I've had some troubles updating a tensor using a previous one.
My problem: let's suppose that I have a tensor `x1` [Nx1] and a new one calculated through the previous, `x2` [Nx1]. Now I want to update the elements of `x2` that are less than `x1`. I'm using `dtype=torch.cuda.FloatTensor`.

> This is the straight code in `Python`:

```
import numpy as np
...
index     = np.where(x1 > x2)
x2[index] = x1[index]
```

> Why can I do this using `PyTorch` with `dtype=torch.cuda.FloatTensor`?
>   And if the `x1` change to [NxD]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks really similar to numpy:

```
idx = (x1 > x2)
x2[idx] = x1[idx]
```

Using some predefined arrays and printing `x2`:

```
x1 = torch.from_numpy(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).float().cuda()
x2 = torch.from_numpy(np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])).float().cuda()
```

> 3  3  3  4  5 
>   [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 5 (GPU 0)]

Code would be the same for NxN dimensional tensors. Using:

```
x1 = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[1, 2, 5], [1, 4, 5]])).float().cuda()
x2 = torch.from_numpy(np.array([[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]])).float().cuda()
```

> 3  3  5
>   3  4  5 
>   [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 2x3 (GPU 0)]